# Hollerith's Radix Sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I have implemented the normal Radix Sort:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(int arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int findMax(int arr[], int n) {
    int mx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > mx)
            mx = arr[i];
    }
    return mx;
}

void countingSort(int arr[], int n, int exp) {
    int output[n];
    const int m = findMax(arr, n) + 1;
    int C[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        C[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        C[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        C[i] += C[i - 1];

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[C[(arr[i] / exp) % 10] - 1] = arr[i];
        C[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
}

void radixSotr(int arr[], int n) {
    int m = findMax(arr, n);
    for (int exp = 1; m / exp > 0; exp *= 10) {
        countingSort(arr, n, exp);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of elements: ";
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Unsorted version of the array: " << endl;
    print(arr, n);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sorted version of the array: " << endl;
    radixSotr(arr, n);
    print(arr, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I am trying to implement Hollerith's version of Radix Sort, where the Radix Sort starts with the most significant bit and propagates iteratively to the least significant bit. Could you give me any ideas how to modify my code, because I am stuck.

Comment: I reverted your last edit, you are not supposed to fix the code in the question from the comments and answers, it makes the discussion inconsistent.  You can add the question with **EDIT** paragraphs at the end of the post to provide more information.

Comment: As answered by Chqlrie, Hollerith is least significant digit first. This is how the old card sorters were used. Most significant first creates an issue, since the buckets can't be combined after each pass, which means 10 buckets after the first pass, 100 buckets after the second pass, 1000 buckets after the third pass, ... .

Comment: Actually I find it horrible that people add "edit paragraphs" instead of rephrasing the original question for clarity, @chqrlie. I also believe that's the way it should be, so do you have any backup for your version? Of course, fixing the faulty code, thus providing an answer without question is bad, I'm not arguing that!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I was probably excessive in my comment, we are on the same line: fixing the faulty code in the question is what I was excluding.  Rephrasing the question for clarity is just as fine as reformatting the code for clarity.  Adding extra precisions, more code, examples, etc. is usually best introduced as edit paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `countingSort` function has a problem:

- you should use an array of `10` indexes for counting instead of finding the largest element and declaring `int C[m]`.  Your current code allocates a potentially huge array in automatic storage, invoking undefined behavior.

Here is a corrected version:

```
void countingSort(int arr[], int n, int exp) {
    int output[n];
    int C[10] = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        C[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        C[i] += C[i - 1];

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[--C[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]] = arr[i];
        C[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
}
```

Note that this algorithm cannot sort an array with negative numbers.

The Hollerith algorithm uses least significant digit to most significant digit. It was invented for sorting US Census data tabulated on punched cards using tabulating machines. This is a **very** early example of computing for data processing that goes back to **1887**. Punch cards used 2 different character encoding schemes named H-code and T-code all the way to the end of the 20th century, H standing for Herman Hollerith, inventor of these sorting machines, who died in 1929. (see http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/Knuth-Sort.html )

For the most significant bit down to the least significant bit, you need recursion, not an iterative method like the one you have:

- Find the maximum value, hence the maximum exponent to get the most significant digit.
- Sort the array according to the current digit
- For each bucket of elements with the same digit at the current position:

  - if the bucket is empty or has only one element, it is sorted
  - otherwise, recurse on the bucket for the next lesser digit, using `exp/10`.

You can do this with any base >= 2.